# .replace, Se pueden reemplazar más str sin necesidad de crear más lineas de código?

Tags: python

estaba haciendo el siguiente ejercicio: Crear un programa que le repita al usuario todo lo que dice pero con todas las vocales cambiadas por i. Mi duda es que si hay una manera de que con sola una linea de código se puede realizar el cometido o tengo que hacer esto:

```
frase_usuario = input("Introduzca una frase:")

frase_final = frase_usuario.replace("a", "i")
frase_final1 = frase_final.replace("A", "i")
frase_final2 = frase_final1.replace("e", "i")
frase_final3 = frase_final2.replace("E", "i")
frase_final4 = frase_final3.replace("I", "i")
frase_final5 = frase_final4.replace("i", "i")
frase_final6 = frase_final5.replace("O", "i")
frase_final7 = frase_final6.replace("o", "i")
frase_final8 = frase_final7.replace("U", "i")
frase_final9 = frase_final8.replace("u", "i")

print(frase_final9)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Una manera de simplificar el código es refactorizar las instrucciones que se repiten en un ciclo, por ejemplo por cada una de las vocales:

```
frase_usuario = input("Introduzca una frase:")
for vocal in list("aeiouAEIOU"):
  frase_usuario = frase_usuario.replace(vocal, "i")
```

`list("aeiouAEIOU")` nos retorna en una lista, cada letra por separado, luego simplemente aplicamos el `replace` por cada vocal.

Y también puedes hacer uso de expresiones regulares, aunque puede ser algo más complejo, si nunca las has usado, en particular para definir el patrón:

```
import re

frase_usuario = re.sub(r"[aeiouAEIOU]", "i", frase_usuario )
```

En este caso el patrón `[aeiouAEIOU]` es relativamente sencillo y es "cualquiera de estas letras".

Answer (score 2):

Que te parece esta idea, hacer una iteración por medio de un arreglo de caracteres, me parece mas reutilizable:

```
def remplazoMultiple(cadena, arreglo, nuevaCadena):
  for elem in arreglo :
    if elem in cadena :
      cadena = cadena.replace(elem, nuevaCadena)
        return  cadena

frase_usuario = input("Introduzca una frase:")

frase_final =  remplazoMultiple(frase_usuario, ['a', 'e', 'i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U'] , "i") 

print(frase_final)
```

Espero te sirva de algo.

Answer (score 0):

Python tiene una función específicamente diseñada para cambiar la aparición de muchas letras por otras tantas en una sola instrucción de forma eficiente, y es `str.translate()`

A esta función hay que pasarle un diccionario cuyas claves sean el código ASCII de cada letra que quieres reemplazar, y los valores sean el código ASCII de la letra con la que la vas a reemplazar.

La construcción de este diccionario típicamente se hace con `str.maketrans()`, que recibe dos cadenas, la primera contiene las letras que quieres reemplazar y la segunda las letras con las que vas a reemplazar.

Por ejemplo: `str.maketrans("AEO", "iii")` generará el diccionario `{65: 105, 69: 105, 79: 105}`, que indica que los códigos 65, 69 y 79 ("A", "E", "O" respectivamente) se cambien por el código 105 ("i").

Un ejemplo final:

```
vocales = "AEIOUaeiou"
reemplazo = "i"*len(vocales)  # Tantas "i" como vocales tenía la otra
diccionario = str.maketrans(vocales, reemplazo)

texto = "A mi me gusta evitar los bucles y hacer todo en una sola linea"
print(texto.translate(diccionario))
```

```
i mi mi gisti ivitir lis biclis y hicir tidi in ini sili linii
```